# Background image is not showing up on iPad1 but is on the iPad2

Tags: css, ipad, background-image, ipad-2

My websites background image: [Click Here](http://bouncebubble.com/v1.6) is not showing up on an ipad1  but is on ipad 2 any ideas? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: The background seems to have tons of styles, try removing some of them... and I checked on my ipad1, you're right it doesn't show, it's not just your ipad

Comment: what do you mean? iv used sprites as background images.

Comment: uh nevermind, firebug confused me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iPad1 has less memory, so larger images don't show up on it. You should make the image files smaller in size.